# Calculating means for a few columns in R

Tags: r

I have read various threads on how to calculate means for various columns in R, but the issue I am running into is that the functions I have used in R so far give me different results than other programs (SAS and SPSS).

So far I have used these functions:

```
newdata2$birdsMean <- rowMeans(newdata2[,7:15], na.rm=TRUE)
(The bird data appears in columns 7 to 15.)
```

and:

```
newdata2$mean=rowMeans(newdata2[,c("bird1", "bird2", "bird3", "bird4", "bird5", "bird6", "bird7", "bird8", "bird9")], na.rm=TRUE)
```

and:

```
newdata2$mean <- rowMeans(subset(newdata2, select = c(bird1, bird2, bird3, bird4, bird5, bird6, bird7, bird8, bird9)), na.rm = TRUE)
```

All of these functions above give me results that are different from SAS and SPSS and since I am working with others who use these other two programs, I am concerned about the differences. In one instance, the differences in the means is as large as 308.

Also, the Median in the aforementioned functions is the same as the Mean for the same variable in SAS and SPSS, but most other results (Min, Max, SD) are different.

So far, the following functions give me results that are consistent with SAS and SPSS:
`mean(newdata2$bird1, na.rm = TRUE)` *((and then I repeated this for other birds and then opened a calculator to get the mean for all birds.))*

and:

```
Supermean <- (mean(newdata2$bird1, na.rm = TRUE) + mean(newdata2$bird2, na.rm = TRUE) + mean(newdata2$bird3, na.rm = TRUE) + mean(newdata2$bird4, na.rm = TRUE) + mean(newdata2$bird5, na.rm = TRUE) + mean(newdata2$bird6, na.rm = TRUE) + mean(newdata2$bird7, na.rm = TRUE) + mean(newdata2$bird8, na.rm = TRUE) + mean(newdata2$bird9, na.rm = TRUE))/9
```

These issue with this method is that I cannot get a nice summary on Mean, median, min, max, sd etc. unless I create a new function for those.

**To summarize, my questions are:**

1) Are there any clear errors in my functions that give me results that are different from SAS and SPSS (SAS and SPSS findings are identical)? I am new to R but I found these functions on other Stack threads.

2) Are there other ways to get the means and nice summary statistics?

3) Isn't it strange that the Median in R is the same as the Mean in SAS and SPSS and why could that be?

4) Which function above is indicative of good/poor practice in R?

5) The means for individual birds are consistent with SPSS and SAS but something goes wrong when I include all birds in the functions that use rowmeans but I don't see any errors.

Due to the inconsistent results, I am hesitant to rely on the above functions for my project. I thought that it might be a rounding error, but that does not explain the difference (I think) as I imported the SPSS file into R and the mean for individual birds in R matches the mean for individual birds in SAS and SPSS. I will be using this method for other variables as well so I am hoping I can get is to work accurately in R. Thanks for you assistance.

Comment: If you want the mean of columns you should use colMeans instead of rowMeans.

Answer (score 0):

From R help:

```
## Compute row and column sums for a matrix:
x <- cbind(x1 = 3, x2 = c(4:1, 2:5))
> x
     x1 x2
[1,]  3  4
[2,]  3  3
[3,]  3  2
[4,]  3  1
[5,]  3  2
[6,]  3  3
[7,]  3  4
[8,]  3  5
rowMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 3.5 3.0 2.5 2.0 2.5 3.0 3.5 4.0
colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE)
x1 x2 
3  3
```

Probably `colMeans` is the way to go

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I did use the cbind: x <- cbind(newdata2$bird1, newdata2$bird2) and then colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) and I get the two means. But then I am creating the category All-birds that contains bird1 and bird2 and I need to get descriptives for that, such as mean of all birds, min, max, and sd.

Is there a neat way to do that in R?

Comment: Maybe to better convey my thoughts, I could do this: y <- colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) and this: summary(y) to get the accurate mean, but then the Min and Max and sd are incorrect because they are just based off of the colMeans.   I am sure there is an easy solution to this that I am just not seeing.

Comment: Then I could do sd(x, na.rm = TRUE) to get the accurate sd. 

Thank you for your answers and I am now getting the accurate results. I still haven't come across a cool feature/package in R yet that could do everything at once (like magically show the mean, sd, etc. for the selected columns at once), so I would love to hear about your recommendations.